# Why can't I adjust exposure on my D90 in aperture-priority mode?

Tags: exposure, aperture, nikon-d90

I have a Nikon D90, and I usually prefer to shoot in Aperture priority mode. However, recently when I go into Aperture mode, I can adjust the aperture, but I can't adjust the exposure, and the hash display that shows if it is over- or under-exposed or spot on, is no longer in the display. I'm hoping there is a simple fix. Maybe I accidentally changed a setting that I didn't realize that took it off?  Anyone know if this is fixable and if so how?

Comment: "I can adjust the aperture, but I can't adjust the exposure" Adjusting the aperture IS adjusting the exposure. Can you explain in more detail? Typically when you are in aperture priority mode you set the aperture and the camera sets the shutter speed based on the meter reading ( because you have told the camera not to change the aperture you have set by choosing aperture priority mode).  You can then use exposure compensation and the camera will adjust the shutter speed according to your choosing plus or minus compensation. Perhaps you can not use exposure compensation ?

Answer (score 1):

If by exposure you mean exposure compensation  look for menu option b2. Easy exposure compensation.

Comment: Thank you!! you are a scholar and a gentleman!!!  I figured it would be something easy like that, and I've been through the menu a dozen times trying to find that setting, and somehow I always missed it.